# Can you help me at formulating question on "which function uses this data and output this scalar value"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've got a set of frequency distribution and output value

i.e.

F[0 1 2 3 6 9 2 5 2 2 1 1 1] = 11.30

F[0 0 2 3 4 6 2 8 2 1 1 1 1] = 41.66

I want to find a function F which gives that returns that output.

Is it a suitable question?

Comment: It depends, is this about Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: This is way too vague. You must describe your problem much better before we can even help you formulate a question.

Comment: I realized that there would be infinite function to try.. the first function tried could be x0 + x1 + x3... the secondo 2*x0 and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not, yet.

- First of all, nothing implies it is about Wolfram Mathematica. We can doubt because we migrate misposted topics everyday
- If it is about Mathematica it is not clear what do you mean by `F[0 1 2 3 6 9 2 5 2 2 1 1 1]` as this is not a correct syntax, unless you meant multiplication.
- Maybe for a specialist this is a clear problem but it should be clear for Mathematica users. And from regular user perspective there is a function `F: R^13 -> R` and two points. Fitting does not make sense unless you elaborate on implicit assumptions/restrictions about `F`.

In general, see [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I realized that the problem is that assuming, for example, only this simple function: F = a * sin(b * x) and F: R^2 -> R we have already 2 possible usages of x1, x2. a=x1, b=x2 or viceversa.. but we may write other million of functions..